# ImageMagick: keep frame dimentions in animation

Tags: php, animation, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif

I've updated my ImageMagick to the latest version, and now I have a problem.
When I create an animation with the following source images:
http://s23.postimg.org/ejff27ycr/pic0.gif
http://s23.postimg.org/4amxweaaz/pic1.gif
The resulting animated GIF is cropped:
http://s16.postimg.org/uargola39/2a6b77b9aeb1367b2b964dd4a865fd58.gif

What am I doing wrong since I didn't change anything?

Here is the command I use to make an animation:
/usr/local/bin/convert -delay 100 -page 300x422 -dispose background /source/*.gif -loop 0 /result.gif

Comment: I've installed previous version of IM (6.7.6-9), and it works now! However, I don't understand why it doesn't work on 6.8.6-10 so my question is still actual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageMagick 6.8.4+ has some changes so if you want to define width and height of new animation you should use the following code:

/usr/local/bin/convert -delay 100 -dispose background /source/*.gif **-repage 300x422** -loop 0 /result.gif